# NSColor to use for selected table view text

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nscolor, macos-mojave

Which NSColor should I use for the text of a selected item in a NSTableView? I have my text field inside a stack view, so the color doesn't get set automatically for selected rows. I tried using `NSColor.selectedTextColor`, but that's still black in 10.13/light mode. For the moment I'm using `NSColor.windowBackgroundColor` but that's not going to work in dark mode, where selected rows change the background color but not the text color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSColor.h in the 10.14 SDK shows this as alternateSelectedControlTextColor:

`@property (class, strong, readonly) NSColor *alternateSelectedControlTextColor;`

```
/* Foreground color inside emphasized and selected content: table views rows, 
collection views, etc. Equivalent to +labelColor in a NSBackgroundStyleEmphasized 
context.*/
```

The latter note was also mentioned in the Advanced Dark Mode wwdc talk:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/218/?time=2161

Where on 10.14 the main label colors will just automatically switch to have the right look inside that selection.

Comment: Thanks! Problem was I was looking in Xcode 9 so I didn't see the new colors.

Comment: Actually,`alternateSelectedControlTextColor` is available starting in 10.12, so I can use it. It just wasn't obvious from the name.